# How to enable http server on asterisk for an ARI application

Tags: asterisk

I am working with ARI( asterisk rest interface ).
I am new in asterisk. 
I want to connect asteris with my localhost using ARI. 
I have done basic configurations but having a problem. 
Here is my http.conf file. I have enabled http server.
[image]
But when i check http status it is still showing disable 
[image]

What i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have check

1) at path you specified there are http files for server

2) firewall not block http server port

Answer (score 1):

On FreePBX you should not edit `http.conf` manually!! You should apply it via GUI:

On FreePBX 2.11

Settings->Advanced Settings->Asterisk Builtin mini-HTTP server->Enable the mini-HTTP Server

Check this link for more info:

http://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FPG/Asterisk+REST+Interface+Users+Module